# How do I send a file with curl or Zend_Http_Client()

Tags: php, zend-framework

Does anyone have an example of sending a file to a zend application using curl. I'm trying to simulate a client sending a file to a server scenario. So I tried these 2 ways, but I'm not getting any post data. This is the curl way with $post data

```
$url = 'http://test.com/test';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
  'file' => '@file.jpg'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response );
```

I also tried this with Zend_Http_Client

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
$client->setFileUpload('file.jpg', 'image');
$response = $client->request();
var_dump($results);
```

What am I supposed to do on the receiver end to receive the file? I'm not getting anything when I output `$this->_request->getParams()`. What is this supposed to look like?

Comment: Are you looking this sort of things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665334/file-upload-using-zend-framework-1-7-4 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` to receive the file on the client side :

```
$adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http(); 

$adapter->setDestination('C:\temp');

if (!$adapter->receive()) {
    $messages = $adapter->getMessages();
    echo implode("\n", $messages);
}
```

Your file will be copied in the destination directory (c:\temp in this case).