# How to get uploaded file name and size before validating that file using zend addvalidator

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

when using zend add validators  for validating a file size and extension.Is it possible to track the file name and size of the file uploaded.Can we get the size and name of the file even when validation fails.I cant track the file name when validation fails as the file not coming to temp directory when validation fails.Is the file validated before storing in temp directory

here is my code snippet:

```
        $document_path_field = $this->CreateElement('file','document_path');
        $document_path_field->setLabel('Document');
        $document_path_field->setAttrib('class','button');
        //$document_path_field->setDestination(SUPPORTING_DOCUMENT_DIRECTORY);
        $document_path_field->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
        $document_path_field->addPrefixPath('Course_Validate_File', 'Course/validate/File', 'validate');
        $document_path_field->addValidator('Size', false, 1000000);
        $document_path_field->addPrefixPath('Course_Validate_File', 'Course/validate/File', 'validate');
        $document_path_field->addValidator('CheckExtension',false,'docx,doc,jpg,png,gif,pdf');                             
        $document_path_field->clearDecorators();
        if(isset($field_required_array['document_path']) && $field_required_array['document_path'] == "Yes")
            {
                $document_path_field->setRequired(true);
            }
            else
            {
                $document_path_field->setRequired(false);
            }
                    $document_path_field->setDecorators($this->setFieldElementDecorators());


        if(in_array('document_path',$field_names_array))
                        {
                                array_push($form_elements,$document_path_field);
                        }   


            $current_document_path = $this->CreateElement('hidden','current_document_path');
            $current_document_path->setLabel('Current Document')
                          ->clearDecorators()
                          ->addDecorator($imageviewScript)
                          ->setValue($this->_document_path);
            array_push($form_elements,$current_document_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted looks like it's for a form, not the controller so it doesn't really help tbh.

Under example #2 here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction.checking

In the second if statement, you can simply get the file name:

```
if (!$upload->isValid($file)) {
    print "Sorry but $file is not what we wanted";
    continue;
} else echo 'File '.$info['name'].' is not allowed';
```

More info: [File Upload using zend framework 1.7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665334/file-upload-using-zend-framework-1-7-4)