# move_uploaded_file() with Zend doens't work

Tags: php, zend-framework

We're building an application within Zend framework and are having trouble moving an uploaded file. We get the file by $filePath = $form->image->getFileName(); but when we're trying to run move_uploaded_file on it, it just returns false.

The image is successfully being uploaded to the temp directory, but we can't move it into a folder.

```
   $formData = $request->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) 
        {
              $form->image->receive();
              $filePath = $form->image->getFileName();
               move_uploaded_file($filePath,APPLICATION_PATH . '\images\new');
         }
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

When I try this, I get 500 - internal server error:

```
            $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();

            $upload->setDestination("C:\xx\xx\public\banners");

            if (!$upload->isValid()) 
             {
                 throw new Exception('Bad image data: '.implode(',', $upload->getMessages()));
              }

      try {
        $upload->receive();
       } 
       catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) 
       {
           throw new Exception('Bad image data: '.$e->getMessage());
       }
```

It seems that it is the "               $upload->setDestination("C:\xx\xx\public\banners");
" that cause the crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equivalent question & answer on stackoverflow should help you out: [File Upload using zend framework 1.7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665334/file-upload-using-zend-framework-1-7-4)

```
//validate file
//for example, this checks there is exactly 1 file, it is a jpeg and is less than 512KB
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->addValidator('Count', false, array('min' =>1, 'max' => 1))
       ->addValidator('IsImage', false, 'jpeg')
       ->addValidator('Size', false, array('max' => '512kB'))
       ->setDestination('/tmp');

if (!$upload->isValid()) 
{
    throw new Exception('Bad image data: '.implode(',', $upload->getMessages()));
}

try {
        $upload->receive();
} 
catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) 
{
        throw new Exception('Bad image data: '.$e->getMessage());
}

//then process your file, it's path is found by calling $upload->getFilename()
```

After using `->receive()` you have already moved the uploaded file so calling another `move_uploaded_file()` is pointless.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edit my question above with your suggestions. I get a crash :(

Comment: @user1251004 Don't know if this will change anything but try this: `"C:\\xx\\xx\\public\\banners"`. Note the double slashes.

Comment: @user1251004 have a look in your error logs see what it says about the 500.